# Using pytest, can I get fixture values outside test function?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I am using parametrizing tests, to test 2 different data sets. For example like this. `some_data()` functions return test data.

```
test_data = [
    (some_data1_v1(), some_data2_v2()),
    (some_data1_v2(), some_data2_v2())
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('a,b', test_data)
def test_fn(a,b):
    pass
```

But for some tests, that checks only general behavior, I don't need to test 2 data sets, because both sets have appropriate general data.
I want to convert `some_data1_v1()` function to fixture and use it in test, like this

```
def test_fn2(some_data1_v1):
    pass
```

If I will do it, then call `some_data1_v1()` during `test_data` list construction raise exception `Fixtures are not meant to be called directly...`

So instead this

```
def test_fn2(some_data1_v1):
    pass
```

I do like this

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('some_data1_v1', [some_data1_v1()])
def test_fn2(some_data1_v1):
    pass
```

This allow me to have one source of test data -  "fake fixtures" (usual functions that return data), and pass test data in `test_data` list (first example or last example). But I think my approach to store data in usual functions is break "fixture abstraction".

Is there a better approach, to do what I do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [parametrized fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures).  `request.param` refers to the specific entry in the `params` sequence

For example:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=(1, 2, 3))
def fix1(request):
    return request.param


@pytest.fixture(params=(4, 5, 6))
def fix2(request):
    return request.param


def test1(fix1, fix2):
    print(fix1, fix2)


def test2(fix1):
    print(fix1)
```

And execution:

```
$ pytest t.py

...

collected 12 items                                                             

t.py::test1[1-4] 1 4
PASSED
t.py::test1[1-5] 1 5
PASSED
t.py::test1[1-6] 1 6
PASSED
t.py::test1[2-4] 2 4
PASSED
t.py::test1[2-5] 2 5
PASSED
t.py::test1[2-6] 2 6
PASSED
t.py::test1[3-4] 3 4
PASSED
t.py::test1[3-5] 3 5
PASSED
t.py::test1[3-6] 3 6
PASSED
t.py::test2[1] 1
PASSED
t.py::test2[2] 2
PASSED
t.py::test2[3] 3
PASSED
```